# How to test threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am learning how to test threads in Python as I have never done it before. I have put a lock in but it says that I have an assertion error which is fine. I am wondering if the following code is correct

```
import threading

i = 0

def test():
    global i
    for _ in range(100000):
        with threading.Lock():
            i += 1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=test) for t in range(10)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

assert i == 1000000, i
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what Lock does. It doesn't lock access to `i`, it just locks access to the lock itself, until it's released. So the 1,000,000 locks your code creates don't do anything useful, they just waste time.

Comment: Could you roll back your question, since this way this question won't be helpful to anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you create a new Lock on every iteration, which is always unlocked.

This way it'll work, because your Threads will try to aquire the same lock.

```
import threading

i = 0

lock = threading.Lock()

def test():
    global i
    for _ in range(100000):
        with lock:
            i += 1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=test) for t in range(10)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(i)
```

Comment: Where should I print to test it out? @pask

Comment: After joining the threads. I added a print statement in the answer.

Comment: @user9590653 Or just put your `assert` at the end of the code.

Comment: what about the assert? thats part of my testing

Comment: You can also put your assert back in.